# Missing ./lib files in node_modules while using allowJs = true with Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am new to NodeJS. I started building an express application where one of my .js files was using requestRetry module. It was working great. Later I decided to slowly introduce Typescript into my project. I converted the basic sections required by express framework to Typescript, but some of my files (the one i mentioned) is still .js.

Here is my tsconfig.js

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "allowJs": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "*": [
                "node_modules/**/*",
                "src/types/*"
            ]
        }
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

The project compiles fine but when I run the application it crashes with

```
module.js:559
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './lib/cookies'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:557:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:484:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:606:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\@MyProjects\OneDriveAriaStats\dist\node_modules\request\index.js:16:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:662:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:673:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:575:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:515:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:507:3)
```

With my current setup, tsc outputs all of the compiled files into the dist folder and also creates a node_modules underneath it since allowjs = true in my tsconfig.js. I dug in further and figured out that lib folder underneath the dist/node_module/request is missing. Its present in the node_module/request.

What am I doing wrong here? Why is tsc not copying over all the required files for request module?

Comment: I faced similar issue. Here, this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/50931553/298455

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the absence of `lib` under `requestretry` in `dist` is the problem. I've looked at the [package.json of `requestretry`](https://github.com/FGRibreau/node-request-retry/blob/54a604a55f5d12267272339d82dfb80f9d0edcad/package.json). Because its declared `main` field is `index.js`, if you're using the [`node` resolution strategy](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#node) in `tsconfig.json`, TypeScript will resolve the `requestretry` module to `node_modules/requestretry/index.js`, thus not involving `node_modules/requesretry/lib/` at all. In fact, there's no `lib` directory inside [that package](https://github.com/FGRibreau/node-request-retry/archive/v1.13.0.zip).

Comment: Ohh sorry about that. The problem is due to the .lib folder under the request npm.